# ReactJs not rendering anchor tag as a link when anchor tag comes inside the string response

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am new to react js and shifting our code from Freemarker to react
I am getting a Json string response which contains anchor tags, when I render this string in react js on browser it shows the anchor tag as a plain text not as a link.

Response:

```
{
    "type": "paragraph",
    "paragraph": {
        "body": " <p> <a href=\"http://stg-testing.com/new-cars/jaguar\" target=\"_blank\">Jaguar</a> <a href=\"http://stg-testing.com/new-cars/landrover\" target=\"_blank\">Land Rover</a> has officially taken the covers off the fifth generation Range Rover SUV which now comes with a new look, new engine options and loaded with new technology with features galore. </p>"
    }
}
```

ReactJS Code:

```
<div className="StoryBodyContent" id={`story_$${storyData.id}`}>
   {storyData.listElement.map(element => 
     (
       <p>{element.paragraph.body.replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","")}</p>
     ))
    }
</div>
```

ReactJS Output:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the innerHTML instead of rendering this as a string.

```html
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={
  element.paragraph.body.replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","")
}></p>
```

Read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

A better implementation would be getting the data you pass to your a tag and transfer it to your JSON data as additional properties instead of passing
the whole anchor tag with data inside.

Refactored Code:

JSON DATA:

```html
{
    "type": "paragraph",
    "paragraph": {
        "body": {
           "firstLink" : "http://stg-testing.com/new-cars/jaguar",
           "secondLink" : "http://stg-testing.com/new-cars/landrover",
           "firstLinkText" : "Jaguar",
           "secondLinkText" : "Land Rover",
           "children" : has officially taken the covers off the fifth generation 
            Range Rover SUV which now comes with a new look, new engine options 
            and loaded with new technology with features galore"
         }
    }
}
```

REACT.JS

```html
<div className="StoryBodyContent" id={`story_$${storyData.id}`}>
   {storyData.listElement.map(element => 
     (
       <p><a href={element.paragraph.body.firstLink}>
              {element.paragraph.body.firstLinkText}
           </a>
           <a href={element.paragraph.body.secondLink}>
              {element.paragraph.body.secondLinkText}
           </a>
           {children}
       </p>
     ))
    }
</div>
```

Comment: The response is coming from the 3rd party api so we don't have any access to change that. 
Also number of links are not limited to any size.